# How to get rid of this circle looking from the render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, height-map

This height texture is made out from a photo, but it leave circle looking thing on the render result. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147242/how-to-get-rid-of-the-odd-lines-shown-in-the-image/147254?r=SearchResults#147254

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181294/why-does-my-displacement-look-jagged-cycles/181298?r=SearchResults#181298

Comment: The image you are using to drive the displacement is a low quality one, most likely 8 bits per pixel. Not enough information to get a smooth transition from one height to the next. Read the links above.

Comment: Thank you a LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has resolved. It is because of the texture image is 1k 8bit. So I used a 32bit 3K image to make the texture for rendering. During this problem, I also discovered Photoshop 3D filter makes pretty good bump and normal textures.

These two articles explained it very well.

[How to get rid of the odd lines shown in the image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147242/how-to-get-rid-of-the-odd-lines-shown-in-the-image/147254#147254)

[Why does my displacement look jagged - Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181294/why-does-my-displacement-look-jagged-cycles/181298#181298)

Keep blending, be safe and peace.

[image]